# Циклический импорт

Tags: python, циклические-зависимости

В своей программе на Python использую классы, которые используют друг друга. Ниже представлен пример

Файл `category_object.py`:

```
from thread_object import Thread
class Category:
  title: str = None
  last_theme: Thread = None
```

файл `thread_object.py`:

```
from category_object import Category
class Thread:
   title: str = None
   text: str = None
   category: Category = None
```

Однако возникает ошибка

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Category' from partially initialized module

Что делать?

Comment: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime_troubles.html#import-cycles

Comment: А ещё ваши аннотации типов запрещают присваивать значение None, а вы прописали None - это неправильно

Comment: Мне кажется, тут не имеет смысла отдельные модули для классов использовать. Можно перенести в один модуль и добавить импорт `from __future__ import annotations` (чтобы можно было использовать класс в аннотациях до его фактического объявления).

Comment: А вам реально нужно, чтобы объекты так друг на друга ссылались? Это какая-то неправильная иерархия объектов )  Нет, ну всякое, конечно, бывает. Но лучше всё-таки решить, какой из объектов выше по иерархии будет.